# Why is GORM returning a nested array for my list property?

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I have the following domain objects:

```
class Foo {
 List<Bar> bars

 static hasMany = [bars: Bars]
 static mapWith = 'mongo'
}

class Bar {
 Foo foo

 static belongsTo = [foo: Foo]
 static mapWith = 'mongo'
}
```

The following code in a service:

```
Bar bar1 = new Bar('bar1')
Bar bar2 = new Bar('bar2')
Bar bar3 = new Bar('bar3')
foo.addToBars(bar1)
foo.addToBars(bar2)
foo.addToBars(bar3)
foo.save
```

And the following code in a controller:

```
def foo = Foo.findAll()
def bars = foo.bars
```

Why is bars a nested array?

I get something like: [['bar1','bar2','bar3']]
I am expecting something like ['bar1','bar2','bar3']

More info:

- Grails 2.4.3
- mongodb 3.0.2
- hibernate 3.6.10.17

Comment: Also, when I debug and inspect the object 'foo', it has the right thing in the 'bars' property, meaning, it has a simple array with the bar objects, but something really f-up is happening when i do foo.bars that is returning that array inside another array

Comment: I don't see any evidence that any arrays are involved anywhere.  Are you using the word "array" as a synonym for a list, or are you really seeing an array somewhere? The distinction is relevant.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown no synonyms and the moment I see the array is when I inspect 'bars' while debugging, it contains and array with 1 item, the first item is the actual array of bars, does that answer your question? thanks by the way!

Comment: It does answer my question.  I don't know where an array could be coming from though unless that is a mongo thing.  I would have expected something that implements `java.util.List`.  Sorry that I can't help.  If you think there is a bug, file a JIRA and we will take a look.

Comment: I just re-read the original post.  What you are saying is almost impossible.  Are you sure that the `bars` property references an array and not an `ArrayList` or some other type of `List`?  An array is a fundamentally different type of thing which doesn't make sense, which is why I asked for clarification earlier.

Comment: The `bars` property is statically typed to be a `List`.  The type of bug required for that to point to an array would be serious and would be beyond Groovy.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Yeah I agree, and the craziest thing about all this is that I have another object with the same mappings to 'bars' and it works perfectly fine with that one :S

Comment: @JeffScottBrown omg I figured it out I'm such an idiot.  So, in the real code, instead of findOne() I had findAll() so that was returning a list of 'Foo's and then I was doing a .bars on that object and that was causing the nested array to be returned!  
Thank you so much anyway Jeff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was doing .bars on the object returned by findAll. I changed it to findOne() and everything worked as expected.

Solution:

```
def foo = Foo.findOne() // was: def foo = Foo.findAll()
def bars = foo.bars
```